# How to set icon to cab file different than base icon on smart device project

Tags: icons, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-ce, smart-device

Hello I am developing a smart device application with .net framework 3.5 to windows ce mobile.

I added icon to my project from Properties > Application > icon and manifest.

My icon is a triangle shape and it needs to has transparent background. I added my icon from properties with transparent background so in mobile device application will have a triangle icon for shortcut.

when I create a cab file for my smart device, it takes icon where I defined from Properties > Application > icon and manifest. But my problem is after installing the application by cab file, it creates square shortcut without transparent background (a triangle and white places).

I need my application shotrcut icon to be seen without white places on smart device.

So I think maybe there is a way to set icon while creating cab file so that it does not take the exe's icon and changes it to a squared icon with white places.

Is there any way to solve my problem?

[my icon with transparent bg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW0Fw.png)

[the icon which cab file produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGUyc.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assuming you are talking about a Windows CE (5/6) or Windows Mobile (5/6) project. So we are talking about "Compact Framework 3.5".

AFAIK only ico files are supported for application icons. That is clear from the file open dialog for Properties > Application > icon and manifest:

[image]

Your png files are not supported as application icon with transparent background.

If the icon is edited as resource inside VS2008, there is a special 'transparent' color:
[image]

This works fine for the Windows Mobile Start menu:

[image]

The icon shown for a cab file is defined by the registry and the same for ALL cab files:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But there are not many colours to make an icon from vs icon editor. Do you know is there a way that we can use more colours or icons should only be from Vs icon editor?

Comment: I am sorry, I do not know how many colors are supported by Windows Mobile 6.5 for icon data. You may try with 256, 16Bit and 24 Bit colors.

Comment: I tried with an external 16Million Colors ico file and it did load and show fine on the device.